# Getting Unexpected '<' in simple less than greater than comparison

Tags: php

I feel very very very silly posting this, but I can't find the answer.  I've searched google and here.

```
// originally values in a multi dimensional array, but used simple values 
// to rule out errors.
$somenumber = 1; $anotherone=5;
if ($somenumber < $res->shares < $anotherone ) {
     //blah
}
```

Get the error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`

Seems pretty simple and straight forward.  Is there some weird thing that you can't compare multiple values?  Do I have to explicitly type?

It works in Perl.  Which of course means that it has to work like this in everything else. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunatly you can't chain comparison operators like that, you need to join them with an and (`&&`). See the following example:

```
$somenumber = 1; $anotherone=5;
if ($somenumber < $res->shares && $res->shares < $anotherone ) {
     //blah
}
```

Comment: apparently, I have to wait 12 minutes to accept.  Thanks!
 I soooo love PHP.  Gah

Comment: @Elizabeth: There are plenty of real reasons to hate PHP. This is not one of them.

Comment: @Ignacio Being able to chain relational operators does lead to more clarity and readability. A minor annoyance.

Comment: @Yacoby: PHP is so full of **major** annoyances that this is just a drop in the bucket.

Comment: It may be a minor annoyance, but there's been so many thing that were easy to muddle through like objects.  This is something I had to post here.  IMHO, it's more than minor.  Gah again.

Answer (score 2):

Chaining relational operators works in very few languages. Type out the full comparison explicitly:

```
if (($somenumber < $res->shares) && ($res->shares < $anotherone)) {
```